# How to ArrayList Object From a Selected Index in Listbox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I have an arraylist that will display data to a listbox. Then, the user can select an entry in the listbox. From there, I need to be able to grab whatever entry they select. I'm using VS 2010.

I have been trying

```
tempArray.Insert(0, myarray.IndexOf(mylistbox.SelectedIndex);
```

All this is doing is giving me the actual index number and not the contents of the index. I'm not sure how to index the arraylist to get the object that is contained at that index.

And yes, I know that I should be using List objects, but it is for class and we have yet to be taught list objects.

Comment: I suggest taking a quick look at the "Accessing Array Members" section here: [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests `.IndexOf()` will return an index from the array.

[Array.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is obviously not what you want.

What you should look at is using the `SelectedItem` instead of the `SelectedIndex`.

That way, you can access the object directly and insert it into your list. One thing to remember is that `SelectedItem` will return an `Object`. This means that it will have to be cast to the type that you expect to be using.

Also, are you wanting to constantly insert items to the top of the list or does it not matter. If you can append it to the end of the list, try using `.Add(yourObject)`.

Answer (score 0):

If these are actual arrays you are working with, shouldn't you be able to to access what's in the array by using the [ ] syntax?  i.e.

```
myArray[myListBox.SelectedIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Dont use ArrayList... that's an old class. Use `List<T>` instead.

2) Have you tried [ListBox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? That seems a bit simpler...